# Css3 transition - on hover overrided element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to make simple animation on element when container is hover. I don't know how it should be written in CSS syntax.

```
<article class="col-md-4 offer-box">
                            <div class="media">
                              <div class="media-left">
                                  <i id="icon" class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>
                              </div>
                              <div class="media-body">
                                  <h4 class="media-heading" id="text-light">Web Design</h4>
                                <p class="text-muted">Pellentesque habitant 
                                    morbi tristique senectus et netus et
                                    malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
                                    Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae,
                                    ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.
                                    Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas 
                                    semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
                                    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
```

```html
#icon{
    color: #ef5925;
    font-size: 35px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
.offer-box:hover{
    #icon{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css syntax is wrong. Write it like this:

```
.offer-box:hover #icon{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;   
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/72/

Comment: Glad I could help @Hirashi :) Do click the tick mark next to the answer to mark this as the correct answer.